# How to use a InfluxDB-tag value in a grafana legend?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have a InfluxDB dataseries. It stores one information about mulitple machines. I distingsh between these machines with a tag. I can display the information for all three machines at once using a "Group by tag(machine)" clause. the name of the legends is "table.derivative {machine: 1}", "table.derivative {machine: 2}" and so on. How can I change it to "machine 1", "machine 2" and so on?

So far I came across [this](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/525) suggesting to use $groupby (or $g ?), but both are just added a literally.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Grafana, you can use alias patterns. There is a description of alias patterns at the bottom of the metrics tab:

[image]

In your case, in the `Alias By` field you would write `$tag_machine`.

Here is an InfluxDb example on the Grafana demo site that uses the `Alias By` field:

https://play.grafana.org/d/000000002/influxdb-templated?editPanel=1&orgId=1

Comment: is it possible to use the Field name ?

Comment: @Wonay did you try $col? You could it use with the alias function (or using AS if writing a raw query: SELECT mean("myfield") AS "myfield")  to get what you want.

Comment: the link is not valid anymore

Comment: @user_x try https://play.grafana.org/d/000000002/influxdb-templated?orgId=1 instead

Answer (score 8):

If you are using InfluxDB with Flux query language, use the following in the `Display Name`

- ${__field.labels}
- ${__field.labels.<tag_name>}

or in some cases this might work

- ${__field.labels.name}

Comment: This helped me big time :) thanks! 
You can also chain the fields, so Display Name can contains something like: `${__field.labels.host}: ${__field.labels.path} (${__field.labels.device})` - example for disk usage

Comment: ${__field.labels.<tag_name>} works for graphite DB as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me `$_tag_TAGNAME` worked ... none of the above worked for me ( even though I saw it in the help section of my instance of Grafana ...)